# Write Parcelable into ContentProvider?

Tags: android

I have a really really huge Object which is Parcelable. It's so big that i dont event want to think of putting all those values into my `ContentProvider` manually. So since my Object already is Parcelable:

**Is there any way of just writing the whole parcelable object into my `ContentProvider`?**

Comment: Why not write a `MyObject.toContentValues()`?

Comment: do you have to use `ContentResolver#insert`? cannot you use `ContentResolver#call`?

Comment: Interesting. Never heard of `ContentResolver#call` whats the difference. Maybe i can use it.

Comment: you can pass `android.os.Bundle` instead of `android.content.ContentValues`

Comment: sounds great. ill try that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution for that! Use the [Google Gson](https://github.com/google/gson) to convert the whole object to a json string:

```
/**
 *
 * @param context
 * @param email
 * @param customer
 */
public static void insertCustomer(Context context, String email, Customer customer) {
    String json = new Gson().toJson(customer);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(DatabaseAdapterCustomer.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_EMAIL, email);
    values.put(DatabaseAdapterCustomer.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_DATA, json);

    final ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();

    resolver.insert(ContentProviderCustomer.CONTENT_URI, values);
}
```

If you select it back you simply need to do:

```
String json = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseAdapterCustomer.COLUMN_CUSTOMER_DATA));

return new Gson().fromJson(json, Customer.class);
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way of just writing the whole parcelable object into my ContentProvider?

No, for the simple reason that `Parcelable` is not meant for storage. It is only for transferring data across process boundaries.